# compare text contents of xml element and add child element to a particular node in Java

Tags: java, xml

i have an arraylist which contains title and fullname in the following format

```
Dr.|ricardo bettati
Prof. Dr.-Ing.|Helmut sperling
miss|angela link
```

First i am splitting the contents with `|`.I will get the title and fullnames. Then i split fullnames with space to get `firstname` and `familyname.`

Now i have 3 strings

String title\which contains title from above list
String firstname;
String familynames;

The next task is i have check the text contents of existed xml with the above strings `firstname` and `familyname`.Here is the existed xml

```
<person>
 <name>
   <firstname>Jean-Luc</firstname>
   <familyname>DeLorme</familyname>
 </name>
</person>
<person>
 <name>
   <firstname>Dave</firstname>
   <familyname>Sperling</familyname>
 </name>
</person>
<person>
 <name>
    <firstname>Helmut</firstname>
    <familyname>sperling</familyname>
 </name>
</person>
```

If the `firstname` and `familyname` contets matches with the text content of above xml elements `<firstname>`,`<familyname>` then i have to create an element named `<title>` and append the corresponding title from my list.My XML supposed to look like the following

```
<person>
 <name>
   <firstname>Jean-Luc</firstname>
   <familyname>DeLorme</familyname>
 </name>
</person>
<person>
 <name>
   <firstname>Dave</firstname>
   <familyname>Sperling</familyname>
 </name>
</person>
<person>
 <name>
    **<title>Prof. Dr.-Ing.>/title>**
    <firstname>Helmut</firstname>
    <familyname>sperling</familyname>
 </name>
</person>
```

I have tried with the following code

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setValidating(false);
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File("Final-Results.xml")));
        Element element =  doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("person");
        for (int i=0;i<titles.size();i++) { //Title is my arraylist
            String names = (String) titles.get(i);
            String[] content=names.split("\\|");
            String title=content[0];
            String[] fullname=content[1].split("\\s+");
            String firstname=fullname[0];
            String familyname=fullname[1];
            for (int n = 0; n < list.getLength(); n++) {

                   Node node = list.item(n);
                   if ("firstname".equals(node.getNodeName()) && node.getTextContent().equals(firstname)) {
                    System.out.println("haii");
                   }
            }
        }
```

But how do i get the children and check the text contents and create node at particular place?

Comment: You can use 'node.getChildNodes()' to get the children. This will give you a list of the children nodes of 'node' and then check anything you want.

Comment: what about people with two first names or middle initials?

Comment: Good question, but as of now i dont have names with 2 first names.But i have names which have middle intial.If i am able to solve this problem,i will be able to handle the names which have middle names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Child node appending:
    Element childElement = doc.createElement("title");
    // set attributes, etc
    node.appendChild(childElement);
```

Code can be simplified with xPath, like:

```
    String xPathExpression = "*/person/name[firstname/text() = 'Helmut' and familyname/text() = 'sperling']";
    XPath path = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList nl = (NodeList) path.evaluate(xPathExpression, doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        Element childElement = doc.createElement("title");
        childElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("Dr."));
        nl.item(i).insertBefore(childElement,((Element)nl.item(i)).getFirstChild());
    }
```

If run code on specified example, result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><result>
<person>
 <name>
   <firstname>Jean-Luc</firstname>
   <familyname>DeLorme</familyname>
 </name>
</person>
<person>
 <name>
   <firstname>Dave</firstname>
   <familyname>Sperling</familyname>
 </name>
</person>
<person>
 <name><title>Dr.</title>
    <firstname>Helmut</firstname>
    <familyname>sperling</familyname>
 </name>
</person>
</result>
```

Comment: Actually i have to get the children of element "name" i.e "firtsname" and "familyname".then check the text contents of these two children.If text contents matched with the partucular names then i have to create element named "title".

Comment: Could you please help me with this problem....appending child to <person> was suceesfull.But i intend to append <title> to <name> tag.the last line  **nl.item(i).insertBefore(childElement,((Element)nl.item(i)).getFirstChild())** look perfect but i did not understand why it is giving error "An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist".

Comment: Strange, code example worked fine, "title" inserted into "name" element.

Comment: All person elements enclosed in one root element <result>. so the above code inserts "title" into "person". Not inside the "name".I should try to get the "name" tag and insert the "title".

Comment: Script result is added, please take a look.

Comment: Possible, you don't applied latest changes, better compare code above with yours. At least, in xPathExpression path "/person/name" must be present.